# UIStackView and a placeholder view in another UIStackView problem

Tags: swift, uikit, uistackview

There is a problem if you have a `UIStackView(testStack)` and a placeholder `UIView(testView)` inside another `UIStackView(mainStack)`. It is meant that if there is no content in the `testStack` it will collapse, and the `testView` will take all the space. There is even a `content hugging priority` set to maximum for the `testStack` so it should collapse its height to 0 when there are no subviews. But it does not. How to make it collapse when there is no content?

PS If there are items in the `testStack`, everything works as expected: `testView` takes all available space, `testStack` takes only the space to fit its subviews.

```
class AView: UIView {
    lazy var mainStack: UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.backgroundColor = .gray
        stack.addArrangedSubview(self.testStack)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(self.testView)
        return stack
    }()
    
    let testStack: UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.backgroundColor = .blue
        stack.setContentHuggingPriority(.init(1000), for: .vertical)
        return stack
    }()
    
    let testView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        backgroundColor = .yellow
        addSubview(mainStack)
        mainStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mainStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        mainStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        mainStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        mainStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: When you add an instance of `AView` to your main view, are you giving it a Height constraint?

Comment: @DonMag I make it edge to superview which essentially gives it hieght

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When auto-layout arranges subviews in a `UIStackView`, it looks at:

- the stack view's `.distribution` property
- the subviews' height constraints (if given)
- the subviews' Intrinsic Content Size

Since you have not specified a `.distribution` property, `mainStack` is using  the default of `.fill`.

A `UIStackView` has **NO** Intrinsic Content Size, so auto-layout says "testStack has a height of Zero"

A `UIView` has **NO** Intrinsic Content Size, so auto-layout says "testView has a height of Zero"

Since the distribution is fill, auto-layout effectively says: "the heights of the arranged subviews are ambiguous, so let's give the last subview a height of Zero, and *fill mainStack* with the first subview.

Setting `.setContentHuggingPriority` will have no effect, because there is no intrinsic height to "hug."

If you set mainStack's `.distribution = .fillEqually`, you will get (as expected) `testStack` filling the top half, and `testView` filling the bottom half.

If you set mainStack's `.distribution = .fillProportionally`, you will get the same result... `testStack` filling the top half, and `testView` filling the bottom half, because `.fillProportionally` uses the arranged subviews' Intrinsic Content Sizes... in this case, they are both Zero, so "proportional" will be equal.

If you set mainStack's `.distribution = .equalSpacing` or `.distribution = .equalCentering`, you won't see either `testStack` or `testView` ... auto-layout will give each of them a height of Zero, and fill the rest of `mainStack` with (empty) "spacing."

If your goal is to have `testStack` "disappear" if it is empty, you can either:

- set it hidden, or
- subclass it and give it an intrinsic height